# xjc/wsimport - JAXB binding ignored

Tags: java, jaxb, wsdl, xjc, wsimport

The wsimport and xjc commands (Both downloaded as part of Java JDK) are ignoring the supplied jaxb binding file when the targeted wsdl/xsds are placed under some specific paths.

To reproduce this behavior, the path **C:\a** can be used.  This directory contains the following XSD files:

**nm.xsd:**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="name.xsd"/>
<xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Annotation</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>

<xs:element name="name" type="Name"/>

<xs:complexType name="FName">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="LName">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

**name.xsd:**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:complexType name="Name">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="FirstName" type="FName"/>
            <xs:element name="LastName" type="LName"/>
            <xs:element name="Date" type="xs:date"/>
        </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**bindings.xjb:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xjc= "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc">
    <jxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false" collectionType="indexed">
        <jxb:javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:date" parseMethod="com.company.Converter.parseDate" printMethod="com.company.Converter.printDate"/>
    </jxb:globalBindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

The following command is used from C:\a to generate the JAXB artifacts:

```
xjc -b bindings.xjb nm.xsd
```

The binding is being ignored.  The generated classes still use xs:date instead of java.util.Date and the adapter class is not getting generated.  Issue is also reproducible when using wsimport with a wsdl that imports the XSD.

When renaming **a** to **d**, the binding is working as expected.  Some paths work and some others do not.  This seems to be random, no pattern was identified.  Behavior is consistent for a given path.
This was reproduced on windows 10, windows 7 and unix machines.  Java version used was 1.7.0_79.  The name of the bindings files does not seem to have an effect, but the name of the XSD files does.

What could be causing this issue and how can this be fixed?  Why does the path affect the binding?  Are there any workarounds that can help avoid this problem while ensuring the binding will not be ignored even if the path changes?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. First of all, there seems to be something wrong with your bindings.xjb file. The closing tag for <jxb:globalBindings> is missing. Then it is odd to have the same method for parsing and for printing (the Converter should e.g. use Converter.print as printMethod). Can you give some further details on which minor version of JDK7 you used and which directory you called the wsimport command from? And could you please print the output of 'tree /f' in the directory you called wsimport and the output of the wsimport command itself? Thanks!

Comment: Hi boskoop, thanks for your reply.  I fixed the global bindings tag and the printMethod (Was not affecting the issue).  I am using jdk1.7.0_79.  I will try to reproduce the issue on a directory that does not disclose confidential information and update the question.

Comment: Attempting to reproduce with sample wsdls and xsds

Comment: So this means that the XSDs in ~\Deskop\config\ws\cccc have an import to the XSDs in ~\Desktop\config\ws\Common directory. Am I right to assume that you are using a relative path (something like schemaLocation="../Common/somefile.xsd")?

Comment: I narrowed the issue down, I will post an update that describes a very easy way to reproduce

Comment: The Date element has the type="xs:dateTime", while your binding file binds the Adapter for xmlType="xs:date" (also there is no printMethod). Is this intentional?

Comment: Thanks, updated.  It wasn't intentional but it doesn't seem to be affecting the result.

Comment: @OrestisP. did you solve this problem? I have a similar issue on one Ubuntu machine. My JAXB bindings are ignored. But if I rename the project directory (just change one letter), it works correctly. Super weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a bug in jaxb-xjc. One issue is reported for these behavior :

https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/issues/1121